# MySQL - How to select only the first X rows that have the same field value?

Tags: mysql, datetime, limit

Here is a simple table that describes an event in a calendar:

```
Event
--------------------
Id      int
DayId   int         # Foreign key to Day table
Title   varchar(32)
Start   datetime
Finish  datetime
```

And an arbitrary SELECT statement to obtain some result set:

```
select
    Id,
    DayId,
    Title,
    Start,
    Finish
from Event
where Start > now()
order by Start
```

The above select query will return **all** events in the future, which is undesirable. But using `limit` means you are required to know how many you want to limit by.

**I would like to be able to select the *first X rows* that have the same `DayId` values.**

---

## Some examples to help explain this situation better:

Example results:

```
Id: 26,   DayId: 08,   Title: "Foo",    Start: "2012-03-19 23:00:00"
Id: 27,   DayId: 08,   Title: "Bar",    Start: "2012-03-20 00:00:00"
Id: 28,   DayId: 09,   Title: "Baz",    Start: "2012-03-21 09:00:00"
Id: 29,   DayId: 10,   Title: "Barbaz", Start: "2012-03-22 11:00:00"
Id: 30,   DayId: 09,   Title: "Fooboo", Start: "2012-03-25 15:00:00"
```

Assuming the above query returned a result set like this, the query that I'm looking for will only return the **first two** rows, as they are the **next occurring events with the same DayId**.

However, after 19th March, the `Start > now()` condition will return a different result set:

```
Id: 28,   DayId: 09,   Title: "Baz",    Start: "2012-03-21 09:00:00"
Id: 29,   DayId: 10,   Title: "Barbaz", Start: "2012-03-22 11:00:00"
Id: 30,   DayId: 09,   Title: "Fooboo", Start: "2012-03-25 15:00:00"
```

And in this circumstance, the result should only return the **first one** row. Note that (for explanatory purposes) the last result *does* have the same DayId, but because it is separated by a different DayId, it should be ignored.

Comment: Can 2 rows with the same `Start` have a different `DayId`?

Comment: I *believe* this is the infamous greatest-n-per-group/group-by-n issue (that MySQL does not handle well) in disguise. I have updated the tags so that there will hopefully be some good links on the right. (I see the tag has been removed -- was I wrong? :-/)

Comment: @MostyMostacho yes, `Start` and `DayId` aren't related at all. It would be a lot simpler to query on the DateTime rather than the foreign key, but due to some requirements in the *real* database, it can't be that simple.

Comment: Got it. So, you said `the result should only return the first one row`. What column is providing the order in the results? I would say it is `start` but I'd better not do any more assumptions :P

Comment: Do you **really** need to do this in one query or two is ok if they are faster than one?

Comment: The column on which to order the results is `Start`, as shown in the query: `order by Start`. Bear in mind that what you quoted from my question is true for only the second example.

Comment: @FractalizeR As long as there is no need for a programming language on top of the SQL (i.e. PHP), multiple queries is OK in this situation.

Comment: @Greg I was going to suggest `SELECT DayId FROM Event where Start > NOW() LIMIT 1` and then `SELECT * FROM Event WHERE DayId=X AND Start > now() LIMIT Y`

Comment: @FractalizeR what is the value of Y?

Comment: @Greg You said: `I would like to be able to select the first X rows`. So, `Y` is your `X`.

Comment: This query would be easily written with `LIMIT 1 WITH TIES`, if MySQL had `WITH TIES`.

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the most optimal way to achieve the desired result, but it will work:

```
select
    Id,
    DayId,
    Title,
    Start,
    Finish
from Event
where Start > now(), AND DayId IN (SELECT DayId FROM Event WHERE Start > now() ORDER BY Start)
order by Start
```

Just realized you can't use LIMIT on a subquery, right now this answer **won't work**

Comment: I agree it might not be optimal, but I hadn't thought of that solution - and it looks like it works, thanks. Can't think of anything better so far, so +1 from me.

Comment: Ah, just tried this and I get the error: `This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot you can't use LIMIT inside a subquery. I'll try to think a way around

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
select id, dayid, title start from (
  select id,
    @equal := @equal and dayId = @dayId ShouldReturn,
    @dayId := dayId as dayId,
    title,
    start
  from t, (
    select @dayId := dayid, @equal := true from t
    where start = (
      select min(start) from t
      where start > now()
    )) init
  where start > now()
  order by start
) as final
where ShouldReturn
```

Comment: Sorry to confuse you, I see what your query was achieving, but due to the fact I've used greatly simplified data to the real database, I missed out an important point: the data must be matched on the DayId, and not the DateTime, as in some cases (now shown in the example data's latest edit) the DateTime overlaps into another date.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, you want all rows with the "first" dayId. So how about this

```
SELECT
  e1.Id,
  e1.DayId,
  e1.Title,
  e1.Start,
  e1.Finish
FROM Event e1.
    LEFT JOIN Event e2 ON e2.DayId>e1.DayId AND e2.Start<e1.Start
WHERE e1.DayId = (
    SELECT MIN(DayId) FROM Event WHERE Start > now()
  )
  AND e2.id IS NULL
```

So, you get the first DayId in all future events in the sub-query and then get all events that have that DayId.

Comment: How will this solution stop `id=30` from being returned in your second example?

Comment: Heh, yes @MostyMostacho - you noticed that! I had to include that case in the examples as it *is* a possibility in the real life application... which makes it a pain.

Comment: @MostyMostacho Ah yes, I thought it was a bit too easy - I missed that requirement. Have updated my answer. It returns just event id 28 on the second data set now.

Answer (score 0):

Chevi's answer is almost perfect. It **should** work, but MySQL has a limitation of not being able to use `limit` inside a subquery. But a simple workaround is possible:

```
select
    Id,
    DayId,
    Title,
    Start,
    Finish
from Event
where Start > now(), 
    and DayId in (

    -- Prepare yourself for a mega-hack!

        select * from (
            select `DayId`
            from Event
            where Start > now
            order by Start
            limit 1

            -- You are allowed a limit here for some reason

        ) alias
    )
order by Start
```

This *does* work, but a sub-sub query acting as a table alias doesn't seem a very optimal solution, so this answer will not be marked as answered, in case someone can help answer the question better.

Comment: How will this solution stop id=30 from being returned in your second example?

Comment: @MostyMostacho because it is ordered by the DateTime field, not in order of the DayId foreign key.

Comment: No, there are many errors in that query: `select *`, `limit 1` and I insist on my previous comment :) Funny thing, I've forgotten to add the `order by` in my query.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    e.*
FROM 
        Event AS e
    JOIN
        ( SELECT DayId
          FROM Event
          WHERE Start > NOW()
          ORDER BY Start
          LIMIT 1
        ) AS good
      ON  e.Start > NOW()
      AND e.Start < COALESCE(
            ( SELECT Start
              FROM Event
              WHERE Start > NOW()
                AND DayId <> good.DayId
              ORDER BY Start
              LIMIT 1
            )
            , '9999-12-31') 
ORDER BY 
    e.Start
```

or:

```
SELECT 
    e.*
FROM 
        Event AS e
    CROSS JOIN
        ( SELECT Start
          FROM 
                Event AS ee
            CROSS JOIN
              ( SELECT DayId
                FROM Event 
                WHERE Start > NOW()
                ORDER BY Start
                LIMIT 1
              ) AS good
          WHERE Start > NOW()
            AND ee.DayId <> good.DayId
          ORDER BY Start
          LIMIT 1
        ) AS bad
WHERE 
    e.Start > NOW()
  AND 
    e.Start < COALESCE(bad.Start, '9999-12-31') 
ORDER BY 
    e.Start
```